# Vue filter state array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My component state has an array named `concessions` with 35 objects, here's the structure of one of those objects:

```
{ 
    address:"Some street"
    brands: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'fiat'
    }]
    city:"Paris"
    contact_name:""
    email:""
    id:1
    latitude:"11.11111"
    longitude:"22.22222"
    name:"AGORA Cars"
    opening_hours:"something"
    phone:"969396973"
    phone2:""
    zipcode:"19100" 
}
```

Now, I have a list rendered with all car brands and a checkbox for each one like this:

```
<div class="brands-filter col-10">
    <span v-for="brand in brands" :key="brand.key" class="brand-card">
        <div>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                :value="brand.name"
                v-model="search_filters"
                @click="filterConcessions()"
            />
            <label class="form-check-label">{{brand.name}}</label>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Basically, for each clicked checkbox, I'm adding the brand to `searched_filters` and after that I want to filter the `concessions` array based on those filters.

In that click method, `@click="filterConcessions()"`, I'm doing this:

```
filterConcessions: function () {
    let concessions = this.concessions;
    let search_filters = this.search_filters;

    let filteredConcessions = [];

    filteredConcessions = concessions.filter((concession) =>
        concession.brands.some((brand) => search_filters.includes(brand.name))
    );
 
    this.concessions = filteredConcessions;
}
```

But, no matter what, it gives me an empty array.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to use the `@change` event instead of `@click`.

Otherwise, `search_filters` isn't populated before `filterConcessions` is run:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    search_filters: [],
    concessions: [{
      address: "Some street",
      brands: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'fiat'
      }],
      city: "Paris",
      contact_name: "",
      email: "",
      id: 1,
      latitude: "11.11111",
      longitude: "22.22222",
      name: "AGORA Cars",
      opening_hours: "something",
      phone: "969396973",
      phone2: "",
      zipcode: "19100"
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    filterConcessions: function() {
      let concessions = this.concessions;
      let search_filters = this.search_filters;

      let filteredConcessions = concessions.filter((concession) =>
        concession.brands.some((brand) => search_filters.includes(brand.name))
      );
      
      console.log(filteredConcessions)

      this.concessions = filteredConcessions;
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="brands-filter col-10" v-if="concessions[0]">
    <span v-for="brand in concessions[0].brands" :key="brand.key" class="brand-card">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="brand.name" v-model="search_filters" @change="filterConcessions()" />
        <label class="form-check-label">{{brand.name}}</label>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some search i figure how to solve this.

I've created a computed method:

```
computed: {
    filteredConcessions() {
      if (!this.search_filters.length) {
        return this.concessions;
      } else {
        return this.concessions.filter((concession) =>
          concession.brands.some((brand) =>
            this.search_filters.includes(brand.name)
          )
        );
      }
    },
  }
```

and at the for loop i iterate throw the "filteredConcessions":

```
<li v-for="concession in filteredConcessions" :key="concession.id" class="p-2">
```

And that solved my case!